# Using Vaadin Flow without internet connection

Tags: internet-connection, vaadin-flow, vaadin12

Is it not possible to develop Vaadin Flow locally on my laptop without an internet connection?

Today I encountered a web page with this message when trying to run my new Vaadin Flow 12 app using Jetty web container bundled in the Vaadin project:

> Project Base for Vaadin Flow
>
> You are offline
>
> Project Base for Vaadin Flow requires an internet connection to work. You do not seem to have access to the server right now. Check your internet connection and try reloading the page to use the application.

Comment: Are you using @PWA annotation in your app? It should enable default service worker, which in case of missing internet connection shows message like that, see https://vaadin.com/docs/v12/flow/pwa/tutorial-pwa-service-worker.html

Comment: @TatuLund (1) Yes, my `MainView` created by the Vaadin 12 starter does indeed have `@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin Flow", shortName = "Project Base" )`. (2) Oddly, I cannot reproduce that pretty Vaadin error page, quoted in the Question, after pulling my Ethernet plug. I have tried several times without internet access, and no problem. My web app is running well locally.